# The api_key isn't set when calling api via Swagger UI

Tags: swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, grape-api, auth-token

I am using Swagger UI to generate api doc and want to call api in this page for grape api.
I set the security_definitions as below:

```
add_swagger_documentation(
  hide_documentation_path: true,
  doc_version: '18.0',
  mount_path: '/api_doc',
  add_version: true,
  hide_format: true,
  info: {
  title: "Search API documentation"
  },
  security_definitions: {
      ApiKeyAuth:{
        type: "apiKey",
        name: "X-Auth-Token",
        in: "header",
        description: "Requests should pass an api_key header."
      }
  },
  security: {
    ApiKeyAuth: []
  }
)
```

But when input the value and sent the request, there is no value in request header.

[Set the apikey value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVfhh.png)

[calling the api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APkzF.png)

Answer (score 1):

`security` is an array so it should be

```
security: [{ ApiKeyAuth: [] }]
```